# Hyperledger Fabric Invalid Channel create transaction : bad header

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm following this guide https://github.com/rohitadivi/Reconfigure-BYFN/blob/master/New-channel-Org3.md to add a third organization to the consortium of the system config of my `./byfn` Hyperledger Fabric network. However, when I get to the "**Sending config update to orderer**" step, I am getting the error `Error: Invalid channel create transaction : bad header`

Here is my `sys_config_update.json`

```html
{
  "payload": {
    "header": {
      "channel_header": {
        "channel_id": "mychannel",
        "type": 2
      }
    },
    "data": {
      "config_update": {
        "channel_id": "mychannel",
        "read_set": {
          "groups": {
            "Application": {
              "mod_policy": "",
              "version": "1"
            },
            "Orderer": {
              "mod_policy": "",
              "version": "0"
            }
          },
          "mod_policy": "",
          "policies": {
            "Admins": {
              "mod_policy": "",
              "version": "0"
            },
            "Readers": {
              "mod_policy": "",
              "version": "0"
            },
            "Writers": {
              "mod_policy": "",
              "version": "0"
            }
          },
          "values": {
            "BlockDataHashingStructure": {
              "mod_policy": "",
              "version": "0"
            },
            "Capabilities": {
              "mod_policy": "",
              "version": "0"
            },
            "Consortium": {
              "mod_policy": "",
              "version": "0"
            },
            "HashingAlgorithm": {
              "mod_policy": "",
              "version": "0"
            },
            "OrdererAddresses": {
              "mod_policy": "",
              "version": "0"
            }
          },
          "version": "0"
        },
        "write_set": {
          "groups": {
            "Application": {
              "mod_policy": "",
              "version": "1"
            },
            "Consortiums": {
              "groups": {
                "SampleConsortium": {
                  "groups": {
                    "Org3MSP": {
                      "mod_policy": "Admins",
                      "policies": {
                        "Admins": {
                          "mod_policy": "Admins",
                          "policy": {
                            "type": 1,
                            "value": {
                              "identities": [
                                {
                                  "principal": {
                                    "msp_identifier": "Org3MSP",
                                    "role": "ADMIN"
                                  },
                                  "principal_classification": "ROLE"
                                }
                              ],
                              "rule": {
                                "n_out_of": {
                                  "n": 1,
                                  "rules": [
                                    {
                                      "signed_by": 0
                                    }
                                  ]
                                }
                              },
                              "version": 0
                            }
                          },
                          "version": "0"
                        },
                        "Readers": {
                          "mod_policy": "Admins",
                          "policy": {
                            "type": 1,
                            "value": {
                              "identities": [
                                {
                                  "principal": {
                                    "msp_identifier": "Org3MSP",
                                    "role": "MEMBER"
                                  },
                                  "principal_classification": "ROLE"
                                }
                              ],
                              "rule": {
                                "n_out_of": {
                                  "n": 1,
                                  "rules": [
                                    {
                                      "signed_by": 0
                                    }
                                  ]
                                }
                              },
                              "version": 0
                            }
                          },
                          "version": "0"
                        },
                        "Writers": {
                          "mod_policy": "Admins",
                          "policy": {
                            "type": 1,
                            "value": {
                              "identities": [
                                {
                                  "principal": {
                                    "msp_identifier": "Org3MSP",
                                    "role": "MEMBER"
                                  },
                                  "principal_classification": "ROLE"
                                }
                              ],
                              "rule": {
                                "n_out_of": {
                                  "n": 1,
                                  "rules": [
                                    {
                                      "signed_by": 0
                                    }
                                  ]
                                }
                              },
                              "version": 0
                            }
                          },
                          "version": "0"
                        }
                      },
                      "values": {
                        "MSP": {
                          "mod_policy": "Admins",
                          "value": {
                            "config": {
                              "admins": [
                                "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"
                              ],
                              "crypto_config": {
                                "identity_identifier_hash_function": "SHA256",
                                "signature_hash_family": "SHA2"
                              },
                              "fabric_node_ous": {
                                "client_ou_identifier": {
                                  "certificate": "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",
                                  "organizational_unit_identifier": "client"
                                },
                                "enable": true,
                                "peer_ou_identifier": {
                                  "certificate": "LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCk1JSUNRakNDQWVtZ0F3SUJBZ0lRZDBIazFTcUg2YURPd1Q0SkhsS3BrakFLQmdncWhrak9QUVFEQWpCek1Rc3cKQ1FZRFZRUUdFd0pWVXpFVE1CRUdBMVVFQ0JNS1EyRnNhV1p2Y201cFlURVdNQlFHQTFVRUJ4TU5VMkZ1SUVaeQpZVzVqYVhOamJ6RVpNQmNHQTFVRUNoTVFiM0puTXk1bGVHRnRjR3hsTG1OdmJURWNNQm9HQTFVRUF4TVRZMkV1CmIzSm5NeTVsZUdGdGNHeGxMbU52YlRBZUZ3MHhPREE1TVRneE9EVTNOVGRhRncweU9EQTVNVFV4T0RVM05UZGEKTUhNeEN6QUpCZ05WQkFZVEFsVlRNUk13RVFZRFZRUUlFd3BEWVd4cFptOXlibWxoTVJZd0ZBWURWUVFIRXcxVApZVzRnUm5KaGJtTnBjMk52TVJrd0Z3WURWUVFLRXhCdmNtY3pMbVY0WVcxd2JHVXVZMjl0TVJ3d0dnWURWUVFECkV4TmpZUzV2Y21jekxtVjRZVzF3YkdVdVkyOXRNRmt3RXdZSEtvWkl6ajBDQVFZSUtvWkl6ajBEQVFjRFFnQUUKbXE0VCtaSGpIWGFqZ0ljU2pRWjhGZFVYWXZsU2NaSjFNcmtyUzg4dTVYRWw1djc4Y2ptdENWdDlyZysrclBXVwpxNkdDV1JsQzQzUkw5dVBaYXdZQ1pxTmZNRjB3RGdZRFZSMFBBUUgvQkFRREFnR21NQThHQTFVZEpRUUlNQVlHCkJGVWRKUUF3RHdZRFZSMFRBUUgvQkFVd0F3RUIvekFwQmdOVkhRNEVJZ1FnY2Q5N1BsV1BnclE1NlphUFJNUUkKdFBqSitPWnpPajI3R05XOVBkYSsrbE13Q2dZSUtvWkl6ajBFQXdJRFJ3QXdSQUlnUVNERmg2YlROcGl2dytoSQprNHViRUY3ZGtZL3NvM1ZzdFJRTXFnSHJidUVDSUFFeDZjVGk0S3BCM2VnYVFCNUVyQVU4QWZnaUpBWFdtNjRICitFZEk1dWRXCi0tLS0tRU5EIENFUlRJRklDQVRFLS0tLS0K",
                                  "organizational_unit_identifier": "peer"
                                }
                              },
                              "name": "Org3MSP",
                              "root_certs": [
                                "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"
                              ],
                              "tls_root_certs": [
                                "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"
                              ]
                            },
                            "type": 0
                          },
                          "version": "0"
                        }
                      },
                      "version": "0"
                    }
                  },
                  "mod_policy": "",
                  "version": "0"
                }
              },
              "mod_policy": "",
              "version": "0"
            },
            "Orderer": {
              "mod_policy": "",
              "version": "0"
            }
          },
          "mod_policy": "Admins",
          "policies": {
            "Admins": {
              "mod_policy": "",
              "version": "0"
            },
            "Readers": {
              "mod_policy": "",
              "version": "0"
            },
            "Writers": {
              "mod_policy": "",
              "version": "0"
            }
          },
          "values": {
            "BlockDataHashingStructure": {
              "mod_policy": "",
              "version": "0"
            },
            "Capabilities": {
              "mod_policy": "",
              "version": "0"
            },
            "Consortium": {
              "mod_policy": "",
              "version": "0"
            },
            "HashingAlgorithm": {
              "mod_policy": "",
              "version": "0"
            },
            "OrdererAddresses": {
              "mod_policy": "",
              "version": "0"
            }
          },
          "version": "1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the configuration update step I am using is this:

```
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# peer channel update -f sys_config_update_in_envelope.pb -c mychannel -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls true --cafile $ORDERER_CA
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

i just ran into this, i'm not sure if this'll help you but it turned out i was running a fabric-tools:1.2.0 on a x86_64-1.1.0 orderer. I versioned them together and it worked for me